# Failed query in Memgraph

Tags: graph-databases, memgraphdb, opencypher

I am trying to execute the following query from [Memgraph's documentation](https://memgraph.com/docs/cypher-manual/clauses/where#17-filter-with-pattern-expressions):

```
MATCH (p:Person)
WHERE exists((p)-[:LIVING_IN]->(:Country {name: 'Germany'}))
RETURN p.name
ORDER BY p.name;
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
Query failed: Not yet implemented: atom expression '(p)-[:LIVING_IN]->(:Country{name:"a"})'
```

Is that a docs error or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check which version of Memgraph you're using? Exists seems like a newly implemented function, so you might be using the older version

Answer (score 0):

Yess, looks like that was the issue. I checked the [changelog](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/changelog) and figured exists function is the v2.6 feature while I was still using the v2.5.2. Thank you!